# Determine fair price of a digital option

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

> A ***digital option*** pays one dollar at time $t = T$ if the asset price is
>   above a fixed level (strike) $K$ and is worthless otherwise.
>
> Consider the following
>   model, with $r = 0$:
>
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> \omega& S(0) & S(1) & S(2) \\ \hline
>  \omega_1&6 & 10&12 \\ \hline
>   \omega_2&6 &10 & 7\\ \hline
>   \omega_3&6 &4 & 7\\ \hline
>  \omega_4&6 &4 & 3\\ \hline
> \end{array}
>
> Evaluate $\Bbb E_\Bbb Q[X]$ and determine the fair price of the digital option struck at $4$.

What I have done for a part that preceded this was find the risk neutral probabilities $\Bbb Q = (p, \frac{1}{3}-p,\frac{5}{12}-\frac{5}{4}p,\frac{1}{4}+\frac{5}{4}p)$ with a restriction on $0<p<\frac{1}{3}$ using systems of equations.

I am not sure how I can find the expectation based on this and what the random variable $X$ represents exactly. I guess the expected value that I am supposed to find will be the fair price?

Comment: I think $X$ should be the asset price, $T$ is the maturity and $r$ is the risk-free interest rate.

Comment: @ʎpoqou, I think that the question asks you to calculate the fair price of the option given as it gives you the strike price of 4. 
What you wrote is a two-step binomial tree with four paths denominated by . 
This means that you need to calculate the risk-neutral probabilities on each path. For the first path, this corresponds to two up moves; for the second path, this corresponds to one up move and one down move; for the third path, this corresponds to one down move and one up move; for the fourth path, two down moves. You get numerical values by doing that.

Comment: For the fair price, you just weight each payoff (S minus K) by the risk-neutral probabilities. Please, let me know if you prefer me going through the calculations in detail. The risk-neutral probabilities that you should find are: Q=(1/9, 2/9, 2/9, 4/9) and the fair price should be of 20/9.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how you got the risk neutral probabilities?

Comment: Calculate the risk-neutral probability of an upmove, which is equal to (6-4)/(10-4)=1/3; the risk-neutral probability of a down move is 2/3. Calculate the probabilities for the paths:
- first path (up-move, up-move) has a risk-neutral probability of (1/3)^2=1/9
- second path (up-move, down-move) has a risk-neutral probability of 1/3 * 2/3 = 2/9
- third path has the same risk-neutral probability as the second path, i.e. 2/9
- fourth path (down-move, down-move) has the risk-neutral probability of (2/3)^2=4/9
Apologies for the brevity. Send me a pvt message for further clarification.

Comment: Also, I've just realized it is a digital option. For the fair price, since it pays one dollar only if the call is in the money, then the payoff will be one when S>K. 
So, the fair value would be: 1/9+2/9+2/9 = 6/9 = 0.33 USD

Comment: That would be $\frac{5}{9}$. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, thank you for spotting the mistake! :)

Comment: How would you go about finding the expected value? Simply multiply elements of $\Bbb Q $ by the values of the asset at time 2?

Comment: The risk-neutral expected value will tell you the price of the digital call option with strike 4. What you're given in the table are the claims of the underlying asset. Therefore, calculate the value for each path: S-K. For path 1, 12-4 and so on. When this payoff is positive, then the digital option pays one; otherwise, it is worthless. To calculate the risk-neutral expectation, then simply sum 1/9+2/9+2/9=5/9 as you multiply each risk-neutral probability by one and 4/9 by zero. Hope this is clear.

Comment: @Waie: These are not the correct probabilities.  This is not an ordinary binomial tree as $S_u/ S_0 = 10/6 \neq S_{uu}/S_u = 12/10$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elementary events $\{\omega_j\}$ correspond to paths on a binomial lattice with transition probabilities $p_1, \, p_2,$ and $p_3$ as shown:

$$\omega_1: \quad S(0) = 6 \underbrace{\to}_{p_1} S_u = 10\underbrace{\to}_{p_2} S_{uu}=12\\\omega_2: \quad S(0) = 6 \underbrace{\to}_{p_1} S_u = 10\underbrace{\to}_{1-p_2} S_{ud}=7\\ \omega_3: \quad S(0) = 6 \underbrace{\to}_{1-p_1} S_d = 4\underbrace{\to}_{p_3} S_{du}=7\\ \omega_4: \quad S(0) = 6 \underbrace{\to}_{1-p_1} S_d = 4\underbrace{\to}_{1-p_3} S_{dd}=3\\$$

The risk-neutral probabilities are found by enforcing expected future prices to be equal to forward prices, which coincide with spot prices as the interest rate is assumed to be $r = 0$.  Under the risk-neutral measure the asset price process is a martingale.

Thus,

$$S(0) = \mathbb{E}[S(1)] = p_1S_u + (1-p_1) S_d\\ \implies 6 = 10p_1 + 4(1-p_1) \implies p_1 = \frac{1}{3}$$

$$S_u = \mathbb{E}[S(2)|S(1) = S_u] = p_2S_{uu} + (1-p_2) S_{ud}\\ \implies 10 = 12p_2 + 7(1-p_2) \implies p_2 = \frac{3}{5}$$

$$S_d = \mathbb{E}[S(2)|S(1) = S_d] = p_3S_{du} + (1-p_3) S_{dd}\\ \implies 4 = 7p_3 + 3(1-p_3) \implies p_3 = \frac{1}{4}$$

We can now compute risk-neutral path probabilities as,

$$P(\omega_1) = \frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{5}, \,\,P(\omega_2) = \frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{5} = \frac{2}{15}, \,\,P(\omega_3) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{4} = \frac{2}{12}, \,\,P(\omega_4) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{2} \,\,$$

The digital option expiring at time $T=2$ with strike $K= 4$ pays $1$ on paths $1,2,3$ and pays $0$ on path $4$.  The fair price is the risk-neutral expected payoff which is

$$\mathbb{E}[X]= P(\omega_1) \cdot 1 + P(\omega_2) \cdot 1 + P(\omega_3) \cdot 1 + P(\omega_4) \cdot 0 = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: That is some beautiful type setting by the way...

Comment: What would you call such a model? A binomial pricing model that changes probabilities at every time step; is it a conditional binomial model?

Comment: @ʎpoqou: Thanks.  The standard binomial model where the up- and down-ratios are constant through time is a discrete approximation of a lognormal random walk (geometric Brownian motion) with constant volatility.  This model is an approximation of a GBM where the volatility changes with time.